# Stabilizers of Segre varieties

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, tensor-products

What, if anything, is known about maps in PGL(V) that preserve Segre varieties?

I am specifically interested in linear maps preserving the Segre embeddings of $\mathbb{P}^{15} \times \mathbb{P}^{15}$ and $\mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^3$ inside $\mathbb{P}^{255}$.